# How to JSONParse parse unicode value in java

Tags: java, eclipse

How to JSONParse parse unicode value in java

```
{"result":1,
"message":"",
"error":200,
"prizeList":{

    "39":{
        "prizeId":39,
        "campaignId":2,
        "prizeType":0,
        "couponType":null,
        "esTypeId":3,
        "title":"\u65e5\u51fa\uff0c\u5617\u9bae",
        "artist":null,
        "songTitle":null,
        "shareText":"\u5167\u6587\u7bc4\u672c",
        "isLimited":0,
        "limit":0,
        "weight":null,
        "backgroundColor":"27B4E8",
        "offerImage":null,
        "productImage":null,
        "sellLineImage":null,
        "walletImage":"http:\/\/mnbd.hercules.smartdrop.com.hk\/phalcon\/public\/prizes\/images\/eds_1_wallet.png",
        "alarmImage320":null,
        "alarmImage800":null,
        "alarmImage960":"http:\/\/mnbd.hercules.smartdrop.com.hk\/phalcon\/public\/prizes\/images\/eds_1_640X960.png",
        "alarmImage1136":"http:\/\/mnbd.hercules.smartdrop.com.hk\/phalcon\/public\/prizes\/images\/eds_1_640X1136.png",
        "audioFileName":"http:\/\/mnbd.hercules.smartdrop.com.hk\/phalcon\/public\/prizes\/audios\/img-30sec.mp3",
        "videoFileName":null,
        "couponTerms":null,
        "downloadable":1,
        "tags":"mcdalarm",
        "expiryDuration":168,
        "activeDate":1392768000,
        "inactiveDate":1395964800,
        "isActive":1,
        "createdOn":1392400385
    }}
```

title, shareText is not parsing. It give after parse to JSON parser ????. How to handle this

Comment: I don't know what JSON parser you use, but it is flawed; try Jackson, it has no problem with such inputs.

Comment: Try this link => http://json.parser.online.fr/  to test your JSON. Once you spot the parse error in your JSON your problem will be solved if other things are working fine.

Comment: It is getting parse fine .Just put two '}}' at the end , as two closing bracket are missing.